# Can't connect to my local hosted bootstrap site

Tags: android, localhost, port

I have recently suddenly been unable to connect to a bootstrap site, hosted on my pc, from my mobile (both tested with ios and android). When i try to connect i write the IPv4 adress of my pc and the port i'm hosting on, which is port 3000.

```
192.168.x.x:3000
```

I'm using browserSync and gulp. I have checked that my pc is actually listening to port 3000 and not only on localhost:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQUBC.png)

But when i try to connect to the port from my mobile it just times out...

Any help is much appreciated

**Additional information:**
I have realised that i was able to connect from my mobile on may 13 ([See browser history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Ewd.png)). So the problem most have occured recently. But as far as i know, there havent been made any changes to my network...

Comment: Is it connected to the same network ? Your mobile and your pc must be connected to the same network.

Comment: @Lester Yes it is. I'm sure both my pc and mobile are connected to the same wifi network.

Answer (score 0):

I did research on this much
And I concluded that there was no connection to the local server on mobile
You will need to test an Android simulator, such as genymotion